# bibliography: bibitem error for beamer in .bbl

Tags: bibliographies

I am having an error in a `.bbl` file and I just cannot find out the problem. I have tried for some time now but I do not really have a clue what it means. This is my `.bbl` file:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi:\discretionary{}{}{}#1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi:\discretionary{}{}{}\begingroup
  \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[{\textit{Ackerman}(2008)}]{Ackerman2008}
Ackerman, F. (2008), {Critique of Cost-Benefit Analysis, and Alternative
  Approaches to Decision-Making}, \textit{Friends of the Earth England, Wales
  and Northern Ireland}, \textit{4}(4), 84--100.

\end{thebibliography}
```

The error is:

```
Use of \@item doesn't match its definition. ...em[{\textit{Ackerman}(2008)}]{Ackerman2008}
```

It has been compiled out of this `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}      
    \usecolortheme{beaver} 
    \usefonttheme{default}  
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{natbib}                         % BibStyles



\begin{document}



    \begin{frame}{Introduction}{The Guardrail Approach}


        \citep{Ackerman2008}



    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{References}
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{tiny}

    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{Text_test}

    \end{tiny}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with the `Text_test.bib`:

```
@article{Ackerman2008,
    author = {Ackerman, Frank},
    journal = {Friends of the Earth England, Wales and Northern Ireland},
    number = {4},
    pages = {84--100},
    title = {{Critique of Cost-Benefit Analysis, and Alternative Approaches to Decision-Making}},
    volume = {4},
    year = {2008}
}
```

By the way, I am using TexStudio. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Delete the bbl file and start over.

Answer (score 2):

Well, with an current version of MiKTeX I can compile your code with no errors.

Please try the following MWE (package `filecontents` is used to have a `bib` file and a TeX code compilable in one MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Ackerman2008,
  author  = {Ackerman, Frank},
  journal = {Friends of the Earth England, Wales and Northern Ireland},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {84--100},
  title   = {{Critique of Cost-Benefit Analysis, and Alternative Approaches to Decision-Making}},
  volume  = {4},
  year    = {2008},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \usecolortheme{beaver}
  \usefonttheme{default}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{natbib}                         % BibStyles


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}{The Guardrail Approach}
  \citep{Ackerman2008}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{References}
  \vspace{3mm}
  \begin{tiny}
  \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
  \bibliography{\jobname} % to use the bib file created by filecontents
  \end{tiny}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Depending on what you have done before it could be that you got an faulty `bbl` file cauing your error.

To be sure please copy my MWE to your computer as---let's say---`mwe.tex`, compile it three times and check the result.  It should show something like:

[image]

If you have still errors, please add command `\listfiles` as first line of the TeX code and recompile three times. Copy the list of used packages and version numbers to your question. You will find this list at the end of the `log` file.